# Mobile Notifications Maintaining: implement own TimeManager or use notifications built-in fireTime manager?

Tags: android, ios, notifications, paradigms, mobile-development

I have to implement a reminder - make the note, then store it in local DB and then make the notification when time comes. I have no experience in mobile development so I'm asking what's better - to implement some time manager that will invoke notifications instantly or store the notifications "as is" to let them be activated by themselves.
What is good approach?

EDIT: I forgot to mention, that I use Xamarin and I've already implemented cross-platform notifications, but now the problem is to choose right way to store and handle them

Answer (score 0):

Use `AlarmManager`, record your `title`, `message` or details of reminder in Database. When alarm is triggered, query your Database to get Title and Message of your notification and show it.

Links:

[Services (AlarmManager)](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html)

[Notification](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html)